# Execute external Java code and get output

Tags: java, shell, command-line, output

I want to **execute a Java CLI-program from within another Java program** and get the output of the CLI-program. I've tried two different implementations (using `runtime.exec()` and `ProcessBuilder`) and they don't quite work.

Here's the peculiar part; *the implementations work (catch the output) for when executing commands such as `pwd` but for some reason they do not catch the output of a Hello World java program executed with `java Hello`.*

## Execution code:

```
public static void executeCommand(String command)
{
    System.out.println("Command: \"" + command + "\"");

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try
    {
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## Example output

```
Command: "cd /Users/axelkennedal/Desktop && java Hello"
Standard output of the command:

Standard error of the command (if any):

Command: "pwd"
Standard output of the command:

/Users/axelkennedal/Dropbox/Programmering/Java/JavaFX/Kode
Standard error of the command (if any):
```

I have verified that `Hello` does indeed print "Hello world" to the CLI when running `Hello` directly from the CLI instead of via `executeCommand()`.

## Hello world

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Runtime.exec pass the command through a shell? I don't think so, but your command needs to be interpreted by the shell to handle &&.

Comment: Aha! Any idea on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Yes. It's been a long time since I've used Runtime.exec, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do any command parsing or invoke a shell first. Being `pwd` is just the command with no arguments it works, but your first command has arguments and needs to be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I do believe seeing somewhere that ProcessBuilder on the other hand can handle things like &&

Comment: I don't see that offhand in the ProcessBuilder javadocs, but I might be missing it. In this particular case, Runtime.exec(new String[]{"java", "Hello"}, null, "/Users/axelkennedal/Desktop") would probably work.

Comment: I don't understand why putting null in the middle would be a good idea, it causes the error "could not resolve method"

Comment: Oops, sorry. The last argument should be a File, not a String. The null is the environment, with null meaning to use the current environment. The final argument is the directory to run the command in, so it replaces the cd at the start of your command. However, I didn't read the javadocs closely enough to notice it's a File and not a String, so wrapping it in new File(...) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "cd /Users/axelkennedal/Desktop && java Hello" is not one command but two commands separated by the `&&`. In general it means do the first command and if the first command succeeds do the second command. You can't pass this as a single command but you can implement the logic yourself:

eg to execute "cmd1 && cmd2"

```
if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd1").waitFor() == 0) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd2").waitFor();
}
```

However, because in this case cmd1 is to change directories there is a better way, which is to use the directory function of ProcessBuilder instead of the first command.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java","hello")
        .directory(new File("/Users/axelkennedal/Desktop"))
        .start();
```

Comment: I just found that in the documentation, which is great :D Thank you!